# Unable to see subview inside UIScrollView through programatically constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add UIView inside UIScrollView using programatically constraints but i think due to constraints missing I'm unable to see UIView. When i tried to add by CGRectMake its working fine also i checked with below code, in view hierarchy there is view inside UIScrollview.

I tried no. of solutions but didn't get any success

[UIScrollView with iOS Auto Layout Constraints: Wrong size for subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441808/uiscrollview-with-ios-auto-layout-constraints-wrong-size-for-subviews/16471244#16471244)

[Programmatically creating controller with UIScrollView and AutoLayout is not sizing the views properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057610/programmatically-creating-controller-with-uiscrollview-and-autolayout-is-not-siz)

Here is my code

```
    vendorDetailsScrollView = UIScrollView()
    vendorDetailsScrollView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    vendorDetailsScrollView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(vendorDetailsScrollView!)

    vendorSubView = UIView()
    vendorSubView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    vendorSubView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.vendorDetailsScrollView!.addSubview(vendorSubView!)

    viewDictionary!["vendorDetailsScrollView"] = vendorDetailsScrollView!
    viewDictionary!["vendorSubView"] = vendorSubView!

    metricDictionary!["navigationHeight"] = navigationHeight
    metricDictionary!["vendorDetailsScrollViewHeight"] = self.view.frame.size.height  - navigationHeight
    metricDictionary!["vendorSubViewHeight"] =  100

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[vendorDetailsScrollView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metricDictionary!, views: viewDictionary!))

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-navigationHeight-[vendorDetailsScrollView(vendorDetailsScrollViewHeight)]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metricDictionary!, views: viewDictionary!))

    self.vendorDetailsScrollView!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-[vendorSubView]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metricDictionary!, views: viewDictionary!))

    self.vendorDetailsScrollView!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[vendorSubView(vendorSubViewHeight)]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metricDictionary!, views: viewDictionary!))
```

Comment: Your `vendorDetailsScrollView` and `vendorSubView` variables aren't `Optional`, so don't use `!` to unwrap them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following code

```
self.vendorDetailsScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vendorSubView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: vendorDetailsScrollView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
```

instead of

```
self.vendorDetailsScrollView!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-[vendorSubView]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metricDictionary!, views: viewDictionary!))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a view as a child inside your vendorDetailsScrollView then add all your subviews inside the child view.

Comment: hi vendorSubView m trying to add as subview its also adding but im unable to see.